# Loading data into a SQL Server database of Microsoft Azure VM through SSIS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, ssis-2012

I have come to learn that we can push the source data file from our local machine to Azure VM to load the database of VM's SQL Server. I have activated my Azure trial account and have setup SQL Server in a VM. Now, I am really clueless how to load data from my local machine.

How it can be achieved by using SSIS flow? Trying to search over the internet,  please share any references.

Thanks

Comment: No one here is going to teach you how to use SSIS. Surely you could avail yourself of Google and find some tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to connect from your local machine to the Azure VM. One way of doing this is give your VM a public IP and configure the right firewall rules. An VPN or other tunneling can also work. Your solution also depends on where your SSIS server lives.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by following the steps mentioned in [Connect to a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Azure (Resource Manager)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect/#steps-for-manually-configuring-sql-server-connectivity-in-an-azure-vm)